# Publish an AVRO file to a kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, kafka-producer-api

I have a a file contains the data in an AVRO format data need to publish directly to a kafka topic. Is there any utilities available without much data parsing in my code? Using kafka 1.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the data from the AVRO file and then serialize it into bytes array.

```
final Schema avroSchema = new Schema.Parser().parse(new File("yourAvroSchema.avsc"));            
File avroFile="yourAvroFile.avro"

// Read as GenericRecord
final GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord> genericDatumReader = new GenericDatumReader<>(avroSchema );
final DataFileReader<GenericRecord> genericRecords = new DataFileReader<>(avroFile, genericDatumReader);

// Serialization
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DatumWriter<GenericRecord> writer = new GenericDatumWriter<GenericRecord>(avroSchema);

Encoder binaryEncoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(out, null);

while (genericRecords.hasNext()) {
    writer.write(genericRecords.next(), binaryEncoder);
}
binaryEncoder.flush();
out.close();

// ....
```

Comment: `writer.write` isn't producing to Kafka, here, which is what the question was asking for. I'm not sure you need the `ByteArrayOutputStream`, rather that should be a `KafkaProducer`